# WPF ResourceDictionary cannot locate source

Tags: wpf, user-controls, resourcedictionary

My XAML designer keep screaming "Cannot locate resource xxx.xaml". I have tried both pack application and absolute path URI formats

- `"pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml"`
- `"pack://application:,,,/Subfolder/ContentFile.xaml"`
- `"/AssemblyName;component/FilePath.xaml"`

The project file structure (can't post picture, not enough rep):

```
root/App.xaml
root/MainWindow.xaml
root/Res
root/Res/PalleteBlue.xaml
root/UserControl
root/UserControl/NavigationDrawer.xaml
root/UserControl/Res
root/UserControl/Res/NavigationDrawerResource.xaml
```

`NavigationDrawer.xaml` use `NavigationDrawerResource.xaml`
`MainWindow.xaml` have instance of `NavigationDrawer.xaml`
XAML designer on `NavigationDrawer` has no issues, but on `MainWindow` it keep telling `Cannot locate resource usercontrol/res/navigationdrawerresource.xaml`

Here is resource declaration in `NavigationDrawer.xaml`

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/UserControl/Res/NavigationDrawerResource.xaml"/>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Res/PalleteBlue.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And here is how `MainWindow.xaml` add instance of `NavigationDrawer`

```
xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:InfiniteLite.View.UserControl"

<Grid>
  <uc:NavigationDrawer></uc:NavigationDrawer>        
</Grid>
```

This yields the `Cannot locate resource....` error on `<uc:NavigationDrawer>` tag but the project can debug just fine

Comment: please provide samples of your code

Comment: `FilePath.xaml` located in project root folder?

Comment: @Zam i've edited the post

Comment: Check that the file is set as Resource - right click on it in the solution , Properties

Comment: @Eibi It's already set as `Resource`